# Scheduled SMS Reminders aren't delivering

Tags: scheduled-reminders, sms, civisms, clickatell

I've set up a Scheduled Reminder for an activity with the following parameters:

Activity type= Custom Type
Activity status= Scheduled
When= 1 day before scheduled activity date and time
Recipients= Activity targets
Send as= SMS

I scheduled an activity for myself (I have a valid mobile) to let the system run to see what happened.

CiviCRM recorded 1 activity: Reminder Sent 2nd Jul 2017 12:05 PM which was one day before the activity. But no SMS was actually received. I've checked the clickatell account and there is no record of an attempt, so we know it didn't fail for some reason there.

Am I missing something obvious? Works a treat for email notification, but they want to switch notifications to SMS.

We know the SMS is configured correctly because we can successfully send one-to-one and bulk SMS messages to contacts with mobile numbers and can see them all in clickatell. Lots of credit on the account as well.

CiviCRM 4.6
Drupal 7
Clickatell 3.0

Comment: Hi Heather!  Are you sure that mass SMS is working?  It doesn't work up to 4.6.28 as there's a bug which looks like it will be fixed in 4.6.29.  This sounds like that problem.  The bug is https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17331

Comment: Related question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/403/why-cant-i-send-bulk-sms-even-though-i-can-send-individually/